# One vector data layer with different styles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, style

I have one layer of vector data that I would like to show in two different styles. Is there a way of accomplishing this in QGIS?

I've solved it now by duplicating the the vector layer and add separate styles for the two layers. That works, but there is one problem with this; When I edit an attribute in one of those two layers, the edited data does not appear in the other layer and the categorized symbols do not longer represent the updated data. I have to hit "Refresh" (F5) to make the edited data update in the other layer. This takes time, since there are many other layers in the project and is not a good solution.

Is there a better way of doing this? I'm pretty sure that this can be done in MapInfo and ArcGis where it's possible to have multiple themes (styles in QGIS) for one layer.

The layers are in WFS format.

Comment: If your data wasn't already provided by serever I would suggest to add one layer normally and other as WMS or WFS from GeoServer for example [like I did here](http://ssrebelious.blogspot.ru/2012/02/speeding-up-qgis-rendering-workaround.html). You would edit .shp-file (or data base) and WMS (WFS) would be updated after you pan, zoom, etc. But your data is already WFS and it seems that you want changes to appear at the second layer at the same time as they were added to the first one without using pan, zoom, etc. Am I right? I'm not sure if this would work in either QGIS, MapInfo or ArcGIS.

Comment: BTW is "Use render caching..." enabled in Options->Rendering? If yes - disable it and see if this would help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm told that in the upcoming QGIS 2.6 when joining multiple layers via the **JOINS** option (*Layer Properties* > *Joins*), editing the attributes of one layer will immediately update the attributes of the joining layers so basically in real-time.

If this is the case then you could create a duplicate of the same layer, save it as another shapefile, edit its attributes and remove all but one column (ideally like an "ID" column or similar). Then do a **JOINS** to connect both layers.

Although this is a possible solution for QGIS 2.6, I'm not sure if there's a better method than what you have already done.

QGIS 2.6 is currently scheduled for 2014/10/31.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The layers are in WFS format, will that solution work for wfs-layers?

Comment: Sorry buddy but I haven't use WFS layers so cannot confirm if it's even possible to do a **JOINS**. But I don't see why not since with WFS layers, you can access and edit its attributes. Hopefully others can provide a more useful insight!